# How can you change the color of your input text inside a TextFormField or TextField using a common theme?

Tags: dart, flutter

I know how to change the text color inside individual `TextFormField` using `TextStyle` but I can't figure out how to apply it app-wide using a theme.

Comment: Hi, you unaccepted my answer, let me know what was wrong it it so that I can update it accordingly.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad Sorry, I put it back.

Comment: No worries, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your root widget in `Theme` and apply `data` as follows. Both `TextField` and `TextFormField` will have same color, common theme.

```
Theme(
  data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
    textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme.apply(bodyColor: Colors.green),
  ),
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      TextFormField(...),
      TextField(...),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to wrap every form/text field with a `Theme` widget, you can set the `subhead` property of `textTheme` in your original `ThemeData` as such:

```
ThemeData(
textTheme: TextTheme(
  subhead: TextStyle(color: Colors.green),
),
```

Although, according to the docs subhead is used for the primary text in lists, so I imagine it might have some unwanted effects if you're using lists elsewhere